# Array Pointer in C++

Tags: c++

```
int n;
int *array[8]
cout<<"Enter Number Between 0-9 Only"<<endl;
for(int i = 0; i< 9; i++){
    cout << "Enter Number " << (i + 1) << endl;
    cin >> n;
    if((n >= 0) && (n <= 9))
        array[i] = &n;
    else {
        cout << "Numbers from 0-9 only\n" << endl;
        i--;
    }

}
cout << *array[0] << endl;
}
```

I'm trying to store 9 entered numbers in a pointer array but its not working why?? Can you explain why to me and how to solve it or improve it. I'm just a beginner and its not homework im testing what i had read.

Comment: What is not working exactly? Do you have en error?

Comment: Why are you using int *array[8]? Why the pointer?

Comment: Then you don't need the pointer.

Comment: Why are you trying to mess around with pointers now if you are just a beginner? They belong much farther down the road if you are still confused on arrays.

Comment: this one seems pretty close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548571

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here.

1. You have nowhere to store the values. You have an array of 8 pointers which are all set to point to the same variable n, which is on the stack and so goes out of scope.
2. The array has 8 elements so the loop goes one past the end
3. This is C++ so really best not to use C arrays unless you have a justifiable reason to.

I would have something more like *NB not compiled and run)

```
{
...
std::vector<int> array;

cout<<"Enter Number Between 0-9 Only"<<endl;
for(int i = 0; i< 8; i++){
    int n;
    cout << "Enter Number " << (i + 1) << endl;
    cin >> n;
    if((n >= 0) && (n <= 9))
        array.push_back(n);
    else {
        cout << "Numbers from 0-9 only\n" << endl;
        i--;
    }

}

cout << array[0] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
array[i] = &n;
```

will store the same address in every entry in your array. This is just pointing to `n` so will always point to that value.

Either define the array as an array of integers

i.e. `int array[9];`

and then place the value into that array

i.e. `array[i] = n;`

**OR**

Allocate some memory off the heap

i.e.

```
int *array[9];
...
array[i] = new int;
*array[i] = n;
```

But you will then have to free this memory with `delete` to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: The last bit will give rise to memory leaks unless you are careful - wether the answer is correct does depend on what exactly the OP is trying to do - but I suspect they do not need that complication.

Comment: @mark - I know. I was just about to add that but the phone rang.

Answer (score 1):

You are saving a pointer to n in the array, but you constantly change the value of n.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to mess with pointers here. Change your array definition, how you populate it, and how you display and you should have better luck.

```
int array[9];
...
array[i] = n;
...
cout << array[0] << endl;
```